# Naming and classification of the curve (spiral)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, curves, classical-mechanics

I am looking for explanations how we could classify the curve (spiral) defined by differential equation in polar coordinates:
$r'^2+r^2=(kt)^2$, $r(t=0)=0$, k- Const.

For small angles the curve is similar to Galileo spiral which then transforms into  Archimedean spiral:
a) if $\phi \in (0,t)$, t is quite small, then $r(\phi) \approx k/2 *\phi^2$
b) if $\phi \in (c, + \infty)$, c is quite large positive number, then $r(\phi)=k\phi+o(\phi)$, as $\phi \to \infty$.

I thought that this is a 'mechanical' curve. Indeed, according to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A202407) the junction point of the curve and the ray uniformly rotated in the origin coordinates moves uniformly accelerated. However I failed to find any references to be sure that is a mechanical curve.
The graphic of the curve is also available to see.

[Graphic of the curve](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Archimedes%E2%80%93Galileo_spiral.png)

So what's the right way to classify the curve?

Any explanations are highly welcomed.

PS I think the curve is not an algebraic one as well.

Comment: Let $k=1$; Your differential equation can be replaced by the following arclength constraint $s(\theta_0):=\int\limits_0^{\theta_0}\sqrt{r^2+(dr/d\theta)^2}\,d\theta=\frac12\theta_0^2$. Isn't it ?

Comment: have you produced a graphical representation of this curve ?

Comment: @ Jean Marie Yes, there is a graphical representation of this curve (please see the link above) and due to the definition (uniform acceleration) $S(t)$ is about $t^2$, right

Comment: Thanks. The spiral of Galileo is also described and plotted [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/galilee/galilee.shtml) but is it exactly the same curve ?

Comment: For very small $t$ the spiral similar to Galileo one, approximately. Of course not the same.